# Google Doc embed width on the right hand side of the page not staying constant

Tags: html, css, embed, google-docs

So I've embedded a Google Document on one of my pages, and I'm trying to make it look centred on the page. However I cannot figure out how to get the left and right margins to appear to be the same. My page is responsive to resolutions so it looks good on some and bad on others. The two attached images show what I mean. Any help would be appreciated, I added a border to make it easier to see where the edge of the embed lies. The embed tag is as follows:

`<iframe class="doc" src="#" width="80%" height="1000px"></iframe>`

Setting the width to 100% makes the gap really really large, much smaller and it changes how the text on the document appears.

[1920px width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2fRN.png)
[~1200px width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgQga.png)

Once again, any help would be wonderful.
Thank you.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong,
you'd like to keep the white space of the doc (on the right) when the page is at ~1200px width?

Comment: I like how it looks at ~1200px width, where the margin seems roughly equal to the left side of the document. The problem is when the width becomes larger and it seems to stretch the right margin too far so it looks odd.